# NSComboBox + Dark Mode. How to change table background color?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm struggling with this for a while and I can't manage to find an answer. I just want to upload my new app to iTunes but I know from previous apps that Apple will complain if the app doesn't look great on macOS dark mode. Well, there is no problem with that except for the NSComboBox. I can change the text and the background colors but I don't see how to change the dropDown table colors. I'd be happy if only they remain black over white in dark mode but they change to all black when Dark Mode is enabled.

[image: WTF Cocoa!]

Is there any way to change this behavior? or any good replacement library? I'd like to keep a NSComboBox subclass if possible because I already have the logic, autocompletion, etc

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to explicitly change this. NSComboBox is just broken. (Until I filed a bug report and it was fixed in 10.13, they didn't even draw correctly in Graphite mode). File a bug report with Apple.

Comment: It's sad but it seems this is the right answer. I've ended using the defaults colors for dark mode too.